# Why isn't Steven Seagal listed in the opening credits?

Tags: credits, executive-decision

In [*Executive Decision*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116253/), Steven Seagal is not listed in the opening credits.  His character dies fairly early in the film.  Seagal is a well-known actor and it seems odd that he wouldn't be included in the opening [credits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116253/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv):

> Steven Seagal isn't named in the opening credits.

**Is there any explanation from filmmakers on why Steven Seagal was not listed in the opening credits?**

Comment: He **is** a well known actor... *now*... but was he then?

Comment: @Catija Sure he was.  He was already a well established action star by the time this movie was released in 1996 :)

Comment: @Catija He definitely was. If anything, he was much more back then than *now*. Although the mid-90s might be said to already mark the beginning of his declining carreer, by the late 80s and early 90s, he was definitely a hot asset in Hollywood action cinema. In fact, the film even somewhat seems to *capitalize* on his appearance, with his early death being rather unexpected, which makes his lack of being mentioned in the opening credits even more unusual.

Comment: What's interesting is that if you google "Executive Decision Movie Poster", some have Seagal on it and some don't.  I know that Seagal was always supposed to die early, and that the whole "shock" was supposed to be, "Oh crap, the action star is dead!  Now what's gonna happen??"

Comment: I believe it is because he just didn't have a big enough role in the movie to warrant an opening credit. But for the pure fact he was a well-known actor, his role was relatively small. His role was almost like an extended cameo instead of a full bill lead.

Comment: @RonBeyer Sure, he dies early in the film, but he was also a well established star at that point in his career.  I would at least thought that he would be listed at the end of the opening credits following "and" or something like that to show his importance.  Also, Seagal is known in Hollywood for his ego.  I imagine that he would protest not being in the opening credits.

Comment: http://www.avclub.com/article/richard-riehle-his-long-career-and-short-mustache--251511

Comment: @Catja - that was pretty much around the pinnacle of Seagal's career.  I remember being convinced that he was clinging to a seam on the outside of the plane, to return at the action climax because there would be no way that they'd get rid of him that fast.

Comment: Definitely his finest role to date. It will be very hard for him to top this performance

Answer (score 1):

His role in the movie was extremely minor considering his fame as an actor. He was not involved in the planning of the insertion on the plane, and as already mentioned, he died saving the other character's lives by closing the hatch, knowing that if he didn't, everyone aboard both planes would likely perish.

Although having such a small role for a famous actor isn't common, they usually don't add an opening credit because they do not want fans of that actor to be disappointed by seeing such a small role in the movie, especially when it ends in that character's death early on.

Comment: This doesn't provide any factual proof as to why he's not credited _in this particular movie_ - it's just speculation

Comment: I used to work in the film industry. I asked a producer why I (and many of my coworkers at the time) weren't going to get movie credits for the work that we did, and he told me that every credit costs the studio money (both for the credit itself and the frames it takes to display the credit whether they are rolling or not). He said that even A-list actors don't get opening credits if their role is too small.

Comment: @Luciano - asking to prove a negative is generally considered a logical fallacy.

Comment: Every credit costs the studio money??  Union movies *require* specific credits, they either get listed or the Director get fined for not listing.  I'm curious as to which production company you worked for?

Comment: Every frame costs money, and the more credits you have means more frames you need for the movie. I worked for Industrial Light & Magic, part of Lucasfilm. The unionized workers do all get their credits, but the non unionized people do not. I don't think the SAG cares much in this case on Seagal's behalf, but he probably could have fought for a credit if he wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Steven is not listed because he joined the cast late. It was already in production and asked if he could do any part. The producers said sure. I think he took part of Franks part away from him. Steven did not want any credit. and I doubt if he even got paid for the short scenes he was in.

Comment: I didn't downvote myself but I'm guessing it's because you didn't provide any proof of what you're saying... (e.g. quotes / links to quotes or paraphrasings of quotes from the filmmakers or Steven himself)